# R function - Error argument is missing, with no default

Tags: r, function, parameter-passing

I am testing a simple function in R that should transform a time series object into a data frame.
However the code works fine outside the function but within the function it gives me the error in the object.

```
>fx<-function(AMts) {
  x<-as.data.frame(AMts)
  return(x)
}
>fx()
```

I expeced to have the data.frame x in my environment, but I got 
`Error in as.data.frame(AMts) : argument "AMts" is missing, with no default`

Comment: `fx(AMts = AMts)`. You have to tell the function what you want it to convert. Right now `AMTs` is just a function argument (even if it is the name of a time series in your global environment)

Comment: When you called the fuction fx(x) did you specify an arguement like `fx(AMts)`?

Comment: I did now after reading the explanation by datajoel. and it works. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's inside a function, you need to have "<<-" as the assignment operator instead of the traditional "<-".  <<- tells R to keep the object after the function is done running.

```
>fx<-function(AMts) {
  x<<-as.data.frame(AMts) # "<<-" is what saves "x" in your environment
  return(x) # remove this line; this prints data frame "x" to the console, but it doesn't save it
}
>fx(AMts)
```

EDIT: As the commenters have already pointed out, you aren't including any parameters in your function.  Above I made it fx(AMts) to make it clear you need to pass in AMts to the function too.

Comment: There were two issues he had.  I probably got voted down before the edit which MDEWITT and Greg correctly pointed out first.  But he wants "x" as a data frame in his environment, and the only way to do that is to use <<-